# Node Update : Gitlab CI executes second job in wrong folder

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci

On our build server, I updated Node from 14.18.1 to 18.16.1 (using nvm).
Our project has Gulp : in the gitlab-ci.yml there are 2 jobs, `npm install` then `gulp build`.

It's working with Node 14.18.1. Second job logs `Using gulpfile D:\BuildGitLab\my-project\gulpfile.js`.
But with 18.16.1, second job is launched from Gitlab CI runner folder, instead of project folder! We have the following log : `Local gulp not found in D:\GitLab`

What's happening?